# RavenDB Get DateTime From Server

Tags: ravendb4

For me to get the date and time from the SQL Server server just do the query "select getdate()".
Is there any way I can get the date and time from the RavenDB Server?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no direct way. But, upon saving a document, you get the `@last-modified` param in the document metadata, which is the current server date & time (UTC) at which the document was saved on the server.